# Capture Google map using html2canvas

Tags: c#, google-maps

I am using html2canvas to capture google map image on the click of a button.
There are lot of codes for this but I am not successful in getting an image,all I get is blank image with google icons like street view and sign in image without rendering map(just a grey background) .I used proxy for c# and here is my code. Can you guys tell me what the problem is?

```
  $('#btn_capture').click(function ()
 {

 html2canvas($('#map-canvas'), {
 logging: true, //Enable log (use Web Console for get Errors and Warnings)
 proxy: "html2canvasproxy.ashx",
// useCORS: true,
   onrendered: function (canvas) {
   var img = new Image();
   img.onload = function () {
   img.onload = null;
   document.body.appendChild(img);
    };
   img.onerror = function () {
   img.onerror = null;
   if (window.console.log) {
   window.console.log("Not loaded image from canvas.toDataURL");
  } 
  else {
  alert("Not loaded image from canvas.toDataURL");
       }
       };
  img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); 
       }

    });
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't address your problem, but rather than html2canvas, have you considered using [Static Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/index)? One of it's main features is to retrieve a map as an image.

Comment: @Andy I have read google map docs about static maps but there are usage limits and after that there is payment rt? that is why is decided to look for html2canvas

Comment: @thank you Andy for getting me on right track.